# openweather API .getJSON request returning undefined

Tags: jquery, json

I've read the a lot of similar topics but they haven't helped..

Trying to access this JSON object..

```
{

    "coord": {
        "lon": -83.9,
        "lat": 33.99
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 701,
            "main": "Mist",
            "description": "mist",
            "icon": "50n"......
```

With this script. I have linked to the jQuery CDN, made sure my api key is right, just at a loss here.

```
<html>

 <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>$(document).ready(function(){
  var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=33.9654688&lon=-83.9138728&appid=(This is where the apikey goes)";

  $.getJSON(api, function(data){
    console.log(api.weather.main);
  });
});
</script>
</html>
```

Any help is much appreciated, this is my first time doing api calls so it's a big ol roadblock for me right now.

Comment: Have you tried console.log(data.weather.main)? or console.log(data);

Comment: Try `console.log(data.weather.main);`!

Comment: var api is for the endpoint that you're trying to reach. var data would be the varialbe for the results coming from the endpoint. So you need to log the data variable so that you'll see the returned results coming from the end point.

Comment: I see, it went through but it's still undefined, i think i might have to use stringify

Comment: @Anson When i do `alert(JSON.stringify(data));` it gives me the whole object, but when i do `alert(JSON.stringify(data.weather.main));` it just returns undefined

Comment: @DanielAlexander Dear, I found the problem. You cannot just get value of `main` by using `data.weather.main`, you must give an index of `weather` array for getting specific `Object` in the array. So, try this `console.log(data.weather[0].main);` for retrieving the first `Object` in `weather` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should read `data` like `console.log(data);`?

Comment: So when i do `code`alert(JSON.stringify(data));`code` it gives me the whole object, but when i do alert(JSON.stringify(data.weather.main)); it still says undefined, what's up with that?

Comment: @DanielAlexander can you show result `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`? looks like you set not proper methods/properties.

Comment: @DanielAlexander oh, i see. `"weather": [` is array, but you set it as the object property. it's should be like `data.weather[0].main`

Comment: Oh wow I should have seen that, thanks Jaime. Btw Death Note is great, Obata is great, you have good taste .

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the next steps for retrieving value from the JSON from API.

1. Specify `data` as an `Object`.
2. Retrieve `weather` of `data` as an `Array`.
3. Retrieve `nth` item you need in the `Array` as an `Object`.
4. Retrieve `main` of `nth` Object as an `String`.

See the example of above description.

```js
var mainObj = {
    "coord": {
        "lon": -83.9,
        "lat": 33.99
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 701,
            "main": "Mist",
            "description": "mist",
            "icon": "50n"
        }
    ]
}

console.log(mainObj);
console.log(mainObj.weather);
console.log(mainObj.weather[0]);
console.log(mainObj.weather[0].main);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer Anson, I've got it now